# Combining and removing duplicates in jsonb - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've managed to combine jsonb arrays using `||`, but I'm not able to remove duplicates and `'N/A'` from the jsonb array.

Current code :

```
SELECT
jsonb_path_query_array(column1, '$.key') ||
jsonb_path_query_array(column2, '$.key') ||
jsonb_path_query_array(column3, '$.key')
FROM
table;
```

Current output : (jsonb)

```
['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['N/A', 'AGENT', 'N/A']
['N/A', 'AGENT', 'AGENT']
['SYSTEM', 'N/A', 'N/A']
```

Desired output

```
NULL
AGENT
AGENT
SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `cte` with `array_to_json`:

```
with vals(a) as (
  select jsonb_path_query_array(column1, '$.key') || jsonb_path_query_array(column2, '$.key') || jsonb_path_query_array(column3, '$.key') from data
),
r_na(a) as (
    select (select array_to_json(array_agg(distinct v.value)) 
            from jsonb_array_elements(v1.a) v where v.value::text <> '"N/A"')  
    from vals v1
)
select case when a::text = 'null' then null else a -> 0 end r from r_na;
```

Output:

```
null
AGENT
AGENT
SYSTEM
```